# Design principle for making ajax calls in ReactJS (where to place ajax calls)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have came across scenarios asking myself where should some call be made, e.g. in the parent or the child. I am using the built in ReactJS Context to pass data through the component tree, however, in terms of ajax calls what design principle should be applied? I know the right way to make API calls are inside the `componentDidMount`, however, should I create an ajax api helper class and pass that helper class function into whatever components I need or should I always make an ajax call within the intended component that needs to retrieve or post data? What are good design pattern principles?

---

I do not want to use Redux since my ReactJS project is small and nothing to complex.

Comment: Where is your code? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how are you making the ajax requests right now, an XHR object?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Comment: I always go with this _"should I create an ajax api helper class and pass that helper class function into whatever components I need"_ the new Context works great with it, and you can save your api responses in your helper. It becomes a kind of cache so you will have to manage your own cache invalidating logic.